# Check if MSSQL is running with Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

How can you check in CMD if a particular service is running - Especially MSSQL?

I have a need to do it CMD and not the usual service.msc gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a service is running via the command line with the `sc query` command.

For example, to check if MSSQL is running you might try:

```
sc query MSSQLSERVER
```

Comment: Note the service name will vary depending on which SQL Server is running (eg. Express Edition is `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`) and instances will have their own names. This does mean that SQL Server might be both running (one instance) and not running (another instance) at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

command line, search all MSSQL services:

```
Wmic service where (PathName like '%Binn\\sqlservr%') get caption, name, startmode, state, PathName, ProcessId
```

Output:

```
Caption                   Name              PathName                                                                                 ProcessId  StartMode  State
SQL Server (SQL2K5LOG)    MSSQL$SQL2K5LOG   "C:\App32\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.4\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQL2K5LOG              8288       Manual     Running
SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)   MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS  "C:\App64\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS  0          Disabled   Stopped
SQL Server (SQLLOGPR)     MSSQL$SQLLOGPR    "C:\App64\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLLOGPR\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLLOGPR      0          Disabled   Stopped
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)  MSSQLSERVER       "C:\App64\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sMSSQLSERVER            0          Manual     Stopped
```

command line, search command path like `Binn\sqlservr`:

```
Wmic process where (ExecutablePath like '%Binn\\sqlservr%') get CommandLine, name, ProcessId
```

Output:

```
CommandLine                                                                  Name          ProcessId
"C:\App32\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.4\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQL2K5LOG  sqlservr.exe  8288
```